# Using Burnside's lemma on the cube.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Having $n$ colors, use the lemma to find a formula for the number of ways to color the edges of the cube.

Here is what I have so far: The Burnside lemma says that $\displaystyle |X/G| = \dfrac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} |X^g|$ where $G$ is a finite group, $X^g$ is the set of elements fixed by $g \in G$, and $|x/G|$ is the number of orbits. Now, using $n$ colors, we have the following:

1 identity element leaving $n^6$ elements of $X$ unchanged.

6 90-degree face rotations each leaving $n^3$ elements unchanged.

3 180-degree face rotations each leaving $n^4$ elements unchanged.

8 120-degree vertex rotations each leaving $n^2$ elements unchanged.

6 180-degree edge rotations each leaving $n^3$ elements unchanged.

Using the above results and the formula from Burnside's lemma, we obtain $\dfrac{n^6+6 \cdot n^3 + 3 \cdot n^4 + 8 \cdot n^2 + 6 \cdot n^3}{24} = \dfrac{n^6 + 3n^4 + 12n^3 + 8n^2}{24}$.

I think I did it right but wanted to check with you guys. Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean that you're coloring the 6 *faces* or the 12 *edges?*

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm is correct. But note that you are coloring edges. What you did is not.

For example, for identity, there are actually $n^{12}$ elements fixed. Because there are $12$ edges and each edge has $n$ colors.

Comment: Oh, wow. Thank you guys for pointing out my mistake. I'm working on it now and will ask further questions if I have any. Any help for "edges" will be appreciated!

Comment: I got $\dfrac{n^{12} + 6n^3 + 3n^6 + 8n^4 + 6n^7}{24}$ but when I try $n=2$ or $n=3$, the results seem too large. Thanks for your help.