# burnside lemma cube

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Having n colors, use the lemma to find a formula for the number of ways to color the edges of the cube.

What I have so far:

I got $|A/G| = \dfrac{n^{12} + 6n^3 + 3n^6 + 8n^4 + 6n^7}{24}$ but when I try $n=2$ or $n=3$, the results seem too large. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks good. See [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A060530).

Comment: Is this the same question as [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334462/using-burnsides-lemma-on-the-cube)?

Comment: I think that it would have been better to edit your old question.

Comment: Oh my gosh I love your name.

Comment: @arbautjc: Why don’t you make that an answer, so that the question has an answer.

Comment: It's only a comment: I did no work except computing a few terms and have a look in OEIS, with the only interesting effect that the OP will know the trick now. Besides, it's too short to be accepted as an answer :-)